# How Can Use HTML5 Camera With Anchor point

Tags: android, iphone, html, canvas, camera

On my webpage I use the following code to get user's camera on their mobile device :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

But I can't find a way to apply some effects on this video, like in the picture
below :

[image: a mobile screen with some overlay on it]

Answer (score 0):

On ios you'are out of luck.
The `<input>` `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` will only open the camera app so the user can take a picture from it.
It should be considered as the the popup that shows your filesystem when you pick a file. Obviously, for security reasons, websites can't access it.

On Android though, newest versions of Firefox and Chrome have implemented the [stream/getUserMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/mediaDevices.getUserMedia). 
So there you could do what ever you want with the video stream.

Comment: hi i can use on ios. 
but i can't use have Anchor point camera. (like this picture)

Comment: @user5318144 Did you read my answer ? The video stream you see on ios is the one from the camera app, you can't access it from your webpage. It's like the popup you've got when you try to choose a file from `<input type="file">`, it comes from the OS, you can't access it from your webpage either. So what you need is the gUM API, but, unfortunately, safari doesn't support it, so no browser on ios won't either.